# How to factor $2 - 3p - 3p^2 + 2p^3$ to obtain $ (1-2p) \times (1+p) \times (2-p)$ ?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

> $$2 - 3p - 3p^2 + 2p^3 = (1-2p) \times (1+p) \times (2-p)$$

I want to factor the left hand side to obtain the right hand side.

is there any technique ?

Explain step by step, please.

Comment: what do you mean? if you multiply the three factors on the right side, you'll get the left side. Do you want to know how to factor the left side in order to obtain the right side?

Comment: @tree If you can solve a cubic equation for it's zeros.......

Comment: @exploringnet~Thank you very much for reforming my question. @mau~yes,i want to know how to factor the left side in order to obtain the right side.

Comment: Use [binomial multiplication](http://www.basic-mathematics.com/multiplying-binomials.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah thats too much work you guess a number 1 yields 2-3-3+2  thats not 0 how about -1)
 hey look thats 0 great. that means p+1 is a factor now we know (p+1) divides $2 - 3p - 3p^2 + 2p^3$ so use long division to split it out ie p+1|$2p^3- 3p^2 - 3p +2 $ = $2p^{2}-5p+2$

ie $(2p^{2}-5p+2)(p+1)=2p^3- 3p^2 - 3p +2 $ then complete the squares on the left or go find a textbook that tells u what the quadratic formula is. you can use the method suggest above to guess what values of p may work but don't factor them to try n look for r=0 thats just silly guess them instead.

Especially ina  proof where you already know the roots all you need to do is solve for p on 1 of the 3 and then plug that into the LHS once that equal 0 its a root.

Comment: ~great,great,great.Thank you so much. It is the best answer.Thank you,again.

Comment: @tree Hint: there's a checkbox under the voting arrows...

Answer (score 3):

$$(1-2p) * (1+p) * (2-p)$$
$$(1-2p)*[(1*2)+(1)(-p)+(p)(2)+(p)(-p)]$$
$$(1-2p)*[2-p+2p-p^2]$$
$$(1-2p)[2+p-p^2]$$
$$[(1*2)+(1*p)+(1)(-p^2)+(-2p*2)+(-2p*p)+(-2p)(-p^2)]$$
$$[2+p-p^2-4p-2p^2+2p^3]$$
$$[2p^3-3p^2-3p+2]$$

2.from LHS=>RHS

$$[2p^3-3p^2-3p+2]$$
$$[2p^3-2p^2-p^2-4p+p+2]$$
$$[2p^3-2p^2-4p-p^2+p+2]$$
$$[(-2p)(-p^2+p+2)+1(-p^2+p+2)]$$
$$[(-2p+1)(-p^2+p+2)]$$
$$[(1-2p)(-p^2+p+2)]$$
$$[(1-2p)(-p^2+2p-p+2)]$$
$$[(1-2p)(-p(p-2)-1(p-2))]$$
$$[(1-2p)(p-2)(-p-1)]$$
$$[-(1-2p)(p-2)(p+1)]$$
$$[(1-2p)(2-p)(p+1)]$$
$$(1-2p)*(1+p)*(2-p)$$

Comment: OP clearly mentioned he want $LHS \Longrightarrow RHS$ not otherway round.

Comment: @exploringnet "I want to evaluate the Right Hand Side , not Left Hand Side"

Comment: no, i didn't want (1−2p)∗(1+p)∗(2−p)=[2p3−3p2−3p+2]

Comment: @ZettaSuro: What?? have I said Chinese above?

Comment: @exploringnet means OP wants to compute LHS to get RHS but he stated "I want to evaluate the Right Hand Side , not Left Hand Side."

Comment: @iostream007 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ruffini's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule): the only possible rational factors  of the form $p+k$ are those $k$ of the form $\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ is a factor of the coefficient of the known term and $b$ a factor of the coefficient of the highest-exponent term.

In this case, you should try to divide the left side for $(p+1)$, $(p-1)$, $(p+2)$, $(p-2)$,
 $(p+\frac{1}{2})$, $(p-\frac{1}{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric pattern of coefficients on the left hand side (including signs) tells you that if $p=a$ is a root, then so is $p=\frac 1 a$, so roots come in pairs.

BUT this is a polynomial with odd degree, so one of its roots must stand alone with $a=\frac 1 a$. It is clear that this must be -1 (1 doesn't work). This gets you one root very quickly.

The fact that the roots come in pairs simplifies finding the others using standard methods (or you just have to factorise a quadratic expression)